# Delayed Notifications Xiaomi Redmi Note 11 Pro

Tags: notifications, xiaomi, miui

I ordered the Xiaomi Redmi Note 11 Pro (China ROM) and the phone is doing fantastic except 1 annoying issue.

All my notifications are being delayed and only get delivered when I wake up the screen.

I have tried several things :

```
power management to performance mode
no battery restrictions
no wifi/3g/4g/5g restrictions
allow all apps to autostart
disabled battery restrictions on app level
no battery restrictions
Allow all background data & location access of apps will be enabled
Allow all app notifications, lessbattery life
```

It just seems that the network connectivity is being lost after a certain time of inactivity when the screen is sleeping. For example: Whatsapp web is disconnecting after a while.

This is happening for 2 months now and I'm clueless where I can find a solution. I'm still waiting to flash the ROM to the global version but this hasn't been released yet.

Any help is much appreciated!

Phone specifications:

Android: 11
Miui : 12.5.18Stable (12.5.18.0(RKTCNXM)
Model: 21091116C

Comment: I think you have done most of what [Don't kill my app!](https://dontkillmyapp.com/xiaomi) suggested, but you may check and try the rest.

Comment: I did with no success. It seems to happen only on 4g/5g connections and not on Wi-Fi. Any suggestions maybe?